# SSO with Oracle Application Express and Asp.Net website

Tags: oracle, authentication, windows-authentication, kerberos, oracle-apex

I have a .net website which access oracle application express web application using Iframe, specifically using a unique url for different pages.

Now, I need windows authentication to be used by both .net website and oracle application express as single sign on.

Please suggest how I can achieve the same.

Let me know if there are any open source technology which I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to use the [Thoth Gateway](http://code.google.com/p/thoth-gateway/) to host Apex in IIS (as opposed to Apache, EPG, or the Apex Listener) and use Integrated Windows authentication as described [here](http://ora-00001.blogspot.ca/2012/03/windows-ntlm-sso-with-apex.html).

Comment: Thanks for the information, but maybe I will keep this as last option since it will mean modifying my existing system. I wanted to implement sso without modifying underlying technologies.

Comment: I tried this and it worked for me..Thanks a ton. I will explore other options now maybe LDAP....